# Game disc (age of empires ) reads on one laptop but not another

Tags: windows-8

One of my older laptops that is has windows vista can read the age of empires III install disc. But when i try to open it in my new laptop which has windows 8 it doesn't work. The disc doesn't even show up after clicking "my computer" why? i don't get it

Comment: Can you verify that the disc itself is not marred by way of scratches or gouges? Some kinds of optical drives can be more sensitive to scratches than others, which would impact your ability to read discs.

What kind of drive is it in the first laptop vs the new laptop? CD(-r/w), DVD(-r/w), BD (-r/w)?

Comment: This is a fairly common problem with DVDs -- disks that read OK on one drive will fail on another.  Sometimes copying the disk helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with the operating system, but with the CD/DVD drive you're reading it on. 
CD/DVD combo drives are know to be much more sensitive to the CD media in comparison to plain CD drives. Very often they have minimal tolerances to CD-R and CD-RW media that have been burned on other drives.

To make sure it's readable on the new laptop, I suggest the following:

1. Create an ISO image of the disk on your old computer
2. Transfer the ISO image file to the new computer
3. Burn the ISO image to a new disk on your new computer. Alternatively - why use the CD itself, where you can use virtual CD tools to mount the ISO image and install/play the game (Daemon tool, MagicISO, etc.)
4. Enjoy your game!